# Novel with an alien rabbit invasion

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens

I'm trying to identify a novel about an alien race coming to Earth. They are rabbit-like.

I thought it was Niven or Pournell but I cannot remember the title.  It was *Quotzal* or something like that.

Answer (score 15):

Could this be [*Quozl*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/35179.Quozl) (1989) by Alan Dean Foster?

> *From the bestselling author of Jed the Dead--here is the
>   out-of-this-world comedy that introduced "Flip-A-Mation" (animated
>   flip art inside each book) and the most lovable aliens in the
>   universe...*
>
> ***The Quozl knew they'd love the third planet from the sun. But it never
>   occurred to them that anyone lived there...***

[image: rabbits drawn house]

Comment: Interestingly enough, [Foster was the ghostwriter of the original novelization of Star Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Dean_Foster#Star_Wars) which had been credited solely to George Lucas.