# Book about space alien cats

Tags: story-identification

I read a book when I was young, it was about space alien cats. I believe the title was Quzzles, but I really don't know. The book was stolen from me before I was finished. I don't know much else about it.

Comment: There is nothing here to really go off of. We're going to need much more detail to figure out what you're looking for. Ex - When did you read it? How old did it look then? What did the cover art look like? **Any** other plot details besides "alien cats". Was it a small or large book?

Comment: Maybe *Quozl* by Alan Dean Foster?

Comment: But the [*Quozl*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?3443) are bunny rabbits, not cats.

Comment: @User14111 That's as good an answer as any right now. The name is similar enough, and cats ~= rabbits.

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd Well, cats and rabbits are both mammals, but cats are predators and rabbits are prey, so I think of them as opposites. (Reminds me of the story where Earth is conquered by what we took to be alien space *rats*, but it turned out they were actually alien space *rabbits* who were horrified and left when they found out we were carnivores.)

Comment: @User14111 I was going off more on looks. Small, fuzzy, big ears, colorful, etc.

Comment: In addition to [*Quozl*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/35179.Quozl) (1989), Alan Dean Foster also wrote [*Cat-A-Lyst*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/35152.Cat_A_Lyst) (1991), a novel featuring sapient cats.

Comment: Sounds like even with the meager info from the OP there are enough potential answers to release this question from on hold purgatory.

Comment: @n_b - Okay, I'll post an answer for *Cat-A-Lyst* if the question is reopened.

Comment: When I read the question, I also remembered reading an anthology about cats in space as a child, but I thought that one of the books in the comments might have been the answer...but they weren't! There is also [Cats In Space and Other Places](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/736080.Cats_in_Space_and_Other_Places)

Comment: And then there's the [_Fuzzy Sapiens_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Fuzzy) series by H. Beam Piper. Many of the [book covers](https://www.google.nl/search?safe=strict&dcr=0&biw=1641&bih=884&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=fg7HWrbJK5D5kwXy2KWICQ&q=%22fuzzy+sapiens%22+%22H.+Beam+Piper%22&oq=%22fuzzy+sapiens%22+%22H.+Beam+Piper%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...2592.8664.0.8966.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.qTkCNvYbuH0) depict them as cat-like, although others make them look like monkeys or bears.

Comment: As an aside, after reading this question, I had to go listen to Leslie Fish's filk from The Pride of Chanur.

Answer (score 7):

Thank you all!! [Quozl](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?3443) by Alan Dean Foster is the one!

Comment: It appears that you have found your answer. At the moment this is just a thank you to the commenters who have suggested the answer to you. However, you can convert this into an actual answer and add a brief description of how it matches what you remembered of the book.

Comment: Or let the person who suggested it post the answer and get the rep they deserve, but maybe that's only me

Comment: I wanted to close it as a dplicate of [this old question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/148436/novel-with-an-alien-rabbit-invasion) but then I realized that the answer to the old question was never accepted.

Comment: I don't need to post an answer for *Cat-A-Lyst* now, but I wonder if the OP perhaps thought the cats from that book were in *Quozl*.  The OP might have read both books — same author, published at about the same time, with similarly whimsical plots.

Comment: Don't forget, the young of both cats and rabbits are called kittens