# A ship full of aliens are stranded on Earth. Some Earth people take them in and hide them. They write a fictional kids TV show based on the aliens

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens

I read it in the 90s or early 00s. The book had a single word name that was also the name of the species. The novel had both humorous and serious aspects to it.

One aspect of the alien society I remember was that they always show great respect to their elders. At one point some youngsters are walking near a prisoner, an evil convicted criminal. They all bob respectively to him. They would not dream of being disrespectful to an alien older than them.

The aliens have long ears. They stay with human families for many years. An old human lady is watching human and alien  children play. She says they are all her grandkids, some have long ears and some don't but she loves them all the same.

Everyone thinks it is wise to keep knowledge of the aliens from most of humanity until our society has evovled more and they will not be considered a threat.

Some of the humans who know the aliens produce a cute kids TV show, named after the aliens and sharing their likenesses.They feel that in the future, when their alien guests do reveal themselves, this will help. There will be many humans who grew up thinking of them as cute fictional friends.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is [Quozl](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/35179.Quozl) by Alan Dean Foster.

[image: Cover art]

Vaguely rabbit like aliens (the long ears) land on Earth and secretly build an underground warren to live in. They're eventually discovered by a human family and the question of how to reveal their presence to the world at large involves making a kid's TV show.

Comment: Duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/184988/book-about-space-alien-cats and a few others.